# A better way to run scripts from main file

Tags: python, command, os.system

I have 3 scripts that i want to run one by one,
currently in my main file i have:

main:

```
parser = get_parser()
args = parser.parse_args()
scripts(q1=args.q1, q2=args.q2, q3=args.q3, q4=args.q4)
```

scripts:

```
def scripts(q1, q2, q3, q4):
    
    c1 = 'path/script1.py' \
                    ' -q1 {} -q2 {} -q3 {} -q4 {}'.format(q1,q2,q3,q4)
    os.system(c1)
    c2 = 'path/script2.py' \
                    ' -q1 {} -q2 {} -q3 {} -q4 {}'.format(q1,q2,q3,q4)
    os.system(c2)
    c3 = 'path/script3.py' \
                    ' -q1 {} -q2 {} -q3 {} -q4 {}'.format(q1,q2,q3,q4)
    os.system(c3)
```

I'm looking for a better and safer why to run them instead of os.system, other stuff i tried doesn't seem to work, like imports and execs..

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why not use functions (define 3 scripts as functions in their files) that you can import?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, ideally you would want to import the code and run it directly from your main script/program (if it's Python code).

However, that's not always possible, in which case the recommended way of running external code is with help of the [`subprocess` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html), either via [`subprocess.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) for simple invocations, e.g.:

```py
import subprocess

parser = get_parser()
args = parser.parse_args()
scripts(q1=args.q1, q2=args.q2, q3=args.q3, q4=args.q4)

def scripts(q1, q2, q3, q4):
    subprocess.run([
        'path/script1.py',
        '-q1', q1,
        '-q2', q2,
        '-q3', q3
        '-q4', q4,
    ])

    # Same for c2 and c3
```

or with [`subprocess.Popen()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) for more complex work, e.g.:

```py
def scripts(q1, q2, q3, q4):
    c1_args = [
        'path/script1.py',
        '-q1', q1,
        '-q2', q2,
        '-q3', q3
        '-q4', q4,
    ]
    with subprocess.Popen(c1_args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE) as proc:
        print(proc.stdout.read())
        data = proc.communicate()[0]
        rc = proc.returncode

    print(rc)

    # Same for c2 and c3
```

`Popen()` is quite powerful and has a long list of arguments and options. I would highly recommend reading the documentation and trying to understand at least some of the basic parameters to find out what makes most sense for your use case.

Comment: thanks for the input, i can't run my script like this at the moment because of permission issues in my work area but once i'll get it fixed i'll use it, thanks!